# What's wrong with this GitHub code ownership question?

Tags: discussion, scope

There's this question that I noticed got a close vote: [Does the owner of the github repository own the copyright to the code?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/does-the-owner-of-the-github-repository-own-the-copyright-to-the-code)

Someone left a custom close reason:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be specifically about free/open source projects

Someone else countered it with a comment:

> @*user* this is does not seem off topic to me. I guess the that *question asker* means that the license is a FLOSS license. Is this correct?

Why should this question be off-topic? Personally, I think it should be on-topic - it's a relevant question to users of open source, as they are dealing with a code hosting platform.

Answer (score 5):

I was the one that though this discussion is **not** off topic. The rationale is that code ownership gives the owner the ability to grant the essential FLOSS permissions such as free (as in freedom) code re-use, modification, redistribution permissions, etc. are quite important for FLOSS!

Together with an open attitude and approach to development, I could say that it **defines** FLOSS and makes it different. Therefore this type of questions should be always considered in this forum IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

Plain questions of law, where the licensing of a project are irrelevant, should not be on-topic here. They can be migrated to Law.SE instead.

The first paragraph is off topic for this reason. The second paragraph could perhaps be on-topic, but it's far too vague. (In fact it isn't clear how related it is to the first paragraph.) "A license" could be anything, not just a FLOSS license.

Comment: If you disagree then please provide some specific counter arguments.